# Html and jquery code for two way framing for a video

Tags: php, jquery, html

Please help me how to get this two way video framing with selected timing values in text boxes as shown in following image using html and J query.Thank you guys in advance,please help me.

I have tried the following code ..

**HTML**

```
<div class="control"> 
    <div class="progressBar"> 
        <div class="bufferBar"></div> 
        <!--<div class="timeBar"></div>--> 
        <input class="timeBar time-slider" type="range" value="0" step="any" style="width: 1.66667%;"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
var timeDrag = false; 
/* Drag status */ 
$('.progressBar').mousedown(function(e) { 
    timeDrag = true; 
    updatebar(e.pageX); 
}); 

$(document).mouseup(function(e) { 
    if(timeDrag) { 
        timeDrag = false; 
        updatebar(e.pageX); 
    } 
}); 

$(document).mousemove(function(e) { 
    if(timeDrag) { 
        updatebar(e.pageX); 
    } 
});
```

As shown in the attachment I need to select certain range in a video and I want to display those selected video starting time and ending time in text box.

Comment: We can help only on the code you have tried.

Comment: <div class="control">
   <div class="progressBar">
       
       <div class="bufferBar"></div>
   <!--<div class="timeBar"></div>-->
    <input class="timeBar time-slider" type="range" value="0" step="any" style="width: 1.66667%;">
    
    
    
    
    
    
</div>
</div>

Comment: Jquery code:var timeDrag = false;   /* Drag status */
$('.progressBar').mousedown(function(e) {
   timeDrag = true;
   updatebar(e.pageX);
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   if(timeDrag) {
       timeDrag = false;
       updatebar(e.pageX);
   }
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   if(timeDrag) {
       updatebar(e.pageX);
   }
});

Comment: Above code is for single bar.And i need two bar for selecting starting and ending time.And to dispaly those seletec time values.

Comment: Please edit your question with these code use ctrl+k for code style formatting.